# How to change aggregation binding path dynamically when pressing a button

Tags: sapui5

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
          xmlns="sap.m" 
          xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
          controllerName="z.controller.Main">

  <Page id="page" title="ComboBox" >
 <content>
  <ComboBox name="Drop-down List" id="box0" items="{/country}">
    <items >
       <core:Item  key="{Key}" text="{Name}" id="item0"/>
    </items>
   </ComboBox>
 </content>
 
 <Button text="Change" press="onChange"/>
</Page>
</mvc:View>
```

model1.json

```json
{
    "country": [{
        "Key": "IN",
        "Name": "India"
    }, 
    {
        "Key": "US",
        "Name": "USA"
    },{
        "Key": "UK",
        "Name": "United Kingdom"
    }]
}
```

model2.json

```json
{
    "country2": [{
        "Key": "BD",
        "Name": "Bangladesh"
    }, 
    {
        "Key": "CA",
        "Name": "Canada"
    },{
        "Key": "FR",
        "Name": "France"
    }]
}
```

Main.controller.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "z/models/model"
], function(Controller,JSONModel, localModel) {
    'use strict';
    return Controller.extend("z.controller.Main",{

        onInit: function(){
           
            var oModel = localModel.createJSONModel("models/data/model1.json");
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

            var oModel2 = localModel.createJSONModel("models/data/model2.json");
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel2, "model2");
           
        },

        onChange: function(){

        }
        
    })
});
```

controller.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(Controller,JSONModel) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        createJSONModel: function(filePath){
            var oModel = new JSONModel();
            oModel.loadData(filePath);
            return oModel;

        }
    }
});
```

I have two JSON models and building a combo list using aggregation `binding(items="{/country}")` by reading data from model1. I am trying to fill the same Combolist by reading the data from the model2 on a button press event.

Comment: Is the data static? Or will this come from a backend in the future?

Answer (score -1):

You can switch the model by using it as a prefix `model2>` (as you have defined in the `Main.controller.js` in the `onInit` method) in the binding path:

```js
onChange: function() {
    var oComboBox = this.getView().byId("box0");
    oComboBox.bindItems("model2>/country2", {
        template: this.getView().byId("item0")
    });
}
```

And change the aggregation from `items` to `dependents`.

```xml
<ComboBox name="Drop-down List" id="box0" items="{/country}">
    <dependents>
       <core:Item key="{Key}" text="{Name}" id="item0"/>
    </dependents>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I get the error " Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element" when I invoke bindItems.

Comment: @Md.sapall I have updated my answer with a template function.

Comment: I am getting error "Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element sap.m.ComboBox#idMyView--box0 !". Can you please explain more about "change the aggregation from items to dependents"?

Comment: Did you mean to change xml view as below? <content>
  <ComboBox name="Drop-down List" id="box0" dependents="{/country}"> 
    <dependents>
       <core:Item  key="{Key}" text="{Name}" id="item0"/>
       </dependents>
     </ComboBox>
 </content>

Comment: @Md.sapall No just change the <items> to <dependents>. The property `dependents="{/country}"` must be `items="{/country}"`.

Comment: I am not still clear where to add dependents

Comment: @Md.sapall I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught Error: Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element sap.m.ComboBox#idMyView--box0 !"

Comment: @Md.sapall If you provide the aggretation `items` you have to provide a template or a factory function. If you don't (want to) provide a template, remove the `items` attribute. Then you have to do the initial binding in JavaScript as well. But I doubt this solution will work since the (dependent) template doesn't contain a model path.